# How to modify "version" file content in the package created with electron-packager?

Tags: electron, package.json, electron-packager

**electron-packager** always create a "version" file in the package it creates. At this moment, this "version" file only contents the electron version.

**How to modify the content of this file? How to include my package.json version tag instead of the electron version?**

See inside the "version" file :

[image: file "version" content]

I use this command in my package.json to run electron-packager :

```
"packager-mac64": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=app/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out ./dist-pkg-packager --ignore=distributions  --ignore=dist-pkg-builder --ignore=trash --ignore=csv-excel --ignore=.*win32-x64$ --ignore=.DS_Store"
```

In my package.json, I also have these lines :

```
"version": "1.1.0",

"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "8.2.0"
},
```

**I would want "1.1.0" instead of "8.2.0" in the version file...**